# Check if jquery (or ajax) function is done

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently running this code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".tableCourses td:first").trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".tableTutors tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".tableForms tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".tableDivision tr:eq(2) td:eq(3)").trigger('click');
            }, 800);
        }, 700);
    }, 600);
});
```

What this basically does is activate my `onclick` events for every first cell of every table I have.

Don't judge.. It's what I need. The `setTimeout` is kind of ugly, and it only works half of the time.

The problem is that every table has to be loaded with ajax, which can take some time. When I use this code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.when($(".tableCourses td:first").trigger('click')).then(function() {
        $.when($(".tableTutors tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click')).then(function() {
            $.when($(".tableForms tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click')).then(function() {
                $(".tableDivision tr:eq(2) td:eq(3)").trigger('click');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

the page only executes the first click handler, which is loading the next table. Am I using `$.when` and `$.then` wrong? Is my syntax wrong?

I normally never touch jquery or ajax, so I'm kind of in the dark.

Another note: the first click has to load two tables from two seperate php pages, so that one takes longer.

**EDIT**: I just realised that the `$.when` and `$.then` just work for the click activation, not the entire ajax loads. Any way to detect when those are done?

**EDIT 2**: This is the onclick event, it is almost the same for every click:

```
<script>
    function courseToTutor(id) {
        var clickedCourse = document.getElementById("course" + id).value;
        $.post('loadTutors', {postname: clickedCourse}, function() {
            $('#loadTutors').load('loadTutors.php');
            $('#loadForms').load('loadForms.php');
        });
        ;
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
</script>
```

It is complicated.. lol. I need to somehow check when these functions are done, before I start my next onclick event on page load?

Comment: You must have `$.when` on the ajax event instead of the trigger click. It will not check whether the ajax has finished/not.

Comment: You should do whatever you're doing in the AJAX callback function after it updates the DOM. Then you shouldn't need timeouts or `$.when`

Comment: where is your ajax code? and btw it should be `$(document)`.

Comment: You haven't told us what this is for or what your actual click event handlers look like. Is this actual page logic, or is it a unit test? I highly doubt that there is a way to wait on some side-effect of a click event. There is an intentional layer of separation between events and what their handlers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax has callbacks for `done`, `error` and `always`.

[Check out the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

These functions are activated when call is ended successfully, with error, or eitherway (respectively).

Comment: I can add those to my ajax calls, but how do I check the status inside of another function that is only to be executed on page load?

Comment: don't execute on page load, execute when ajax is done

Comment: But then it would execute my code every time a cell was clicked.. I want the code only to fire once, but the clickhandlers can be executed multiple times.

Comment: give it a global counter, or use a function that you delete

Answer (score 1):

you can use [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
var promise = $.ajax({
  url: "/ServerResource.txt"
});

promise.done(successFunction);
promise.fail(errorFunction);
promise.always(alwaysFunction);
```

kindly check for clear explanation of [making-promises-with-jquery-deferred](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html)

Comment: I understand, but I don't call on any ajax directly in my `$(document).ready`, so where am I supposed to add the promises? If I add them in my onclick functions, I'd load the same thing every time I click on something

Answer (score 0):

In order for then to be triggered you need to use a function that returns an appropriate response. When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, usually by the code that created the Deferred originally, the appropriate callbacks will be called. For example, the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.ajax() is a Promise-compatible object. Trigger does not return a Promise-compatible, so you should manually return a success Promise-compatible object. For example:

```
var myResponse = $.Deferred();
$(".tableTutors tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click');
myResponse .resolve( "clicked" );
$.when(myResponse ).then(function() {
  $(".tableForms tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").trigger('click')
});
....
```

Comment: This results in exactly the same way. I think it still checks whether something is clicked, not whether something is loaded?